# Node.js ignores all querystring parameters except the first one

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, curl, query-string

I can't persuade Node.js to see the second parameter from my URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/cities?tag=123&date=2013-03-30T10:00:28.000%2B02:00
```

I start the Node.js server with the following command:

```
node --debug ./router_rest.js
```

I have the following code in my "router_rest.js" file:

```
require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
  //  For PUT/POST methods, wait until the
  //  complete request body has been read.
  if (req.method==="POST" || req.method==="PUT") {
    var body = "";
    req.on("data", function(data){
      body += data;
    })

    req.on("end", function(){
      return routeCall(req, res, body);
    })

  } else {
    return routeCall(req, res, "");
  }
}).listen(8888);
```

I make the following call from the command line:

```
curl http://localhost:8888/cities?tag=123&date=2013-03-30T10:00:28.000%2B02:00
```

When I debug and examine the 'req' parameter (in the anonymous function above), the url property appears as:

```
/cities?tag=123
```

I was expecting the url reported to be:

```
/cities?tag=123&date=2013-03-30T10:00:28.000%2B02:00
```

Even when I switch parameters, node still only sees the first one.

Why has the last parameter (ie. date) been truncated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Node is fine.

The first ampersand in your `curl` command is causing the shell to run curl in the background. Add quotes around the URL and it will work.

```
curl "http://localhost:8888/cities?tag=123&date=2013-03-30T10:00:28.000%2B02:00"
```

Comment: Ah yes... looking for the problem in completely the wrong place. Thx.